# Pegar dados de campos de mesmo nome mas de tabelas diferentes

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, query, join

Tenho um select que ele busca dados de três tabelas diferentes, mas tem alguns campos em comum entre essas três tabelas. Minha dúvida é como pegar os dados desse campos, que tem o nome em comum com as outras tabelas.

Meu select está assim:

```
    SELECT suporte_cad.reg,suporte_cad.data,suporte_cad.status,
    suporte_cad.nmcontato, suporte_cad.mensagem ,
    serv_cad.nmgrupo,serv_cad.dsservico, suporte_det.reg, 
    suporte_det.data, suporte_det.nmContato, suporte_det.nmUsuario, 
    suporte_det.mensagem

    FROM suporte_cad,serv_cad,suporte_det where cnpj='$getCnpj'
    and suporte_cad.idservcad=serv_cad.idservcad and suporte_det.reg='$reg'
    and suporte_cad.reg = '$reg'
```

Quero pegar o campo mensagem  da tabelas ***suporte_cad*** e ***suporte_det***

Comment: Não entendi, você está pegando os campos que deseja.

Comment: SQL AS http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Comment: @bigown Estou supondo que o problema é na outra ponta (PHP?), na hora de ler os resultados pelo nome da coluna.

Comment: @bfavaretto matou, acho que é isto mesmo, ele iria usar em outro lugar, talvez até no `JOIN` que seria colocado depois.

Comment: O ALIAS me resolveu, fez exatamente o que eu queria

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use um *alias* em cada um desses campos, que você define com `AS`:

```
SELECT 
    suporte_cad.reg,
    suporte_cad.data,
    suporte_cad.status,
    suporte_cad.nmcontato, 
    suporte_cad.mensagem AS mensagem_cad,
    serv_cad.nmgrupo,
    serv_cad.dsservico, 
    suporte_det.reg, 
    suporte_det.data, 
    suporte_det.nmContato, 
    suporte_det.nmUsuario, 
    suporte_det.mensagem AS mensagem_det
...
```